# Execute method in post commit

Tags: future

I have a requirement where i would like to call an apex method after the record is committed to the database , is there a way i can do that ? I see that @future can be used but i am not sure if it gets called only after a record is committed to the database .

Comment: What is your exact requirements?  What do you want to perform in post commit?

Answer (score 1):

Future methods are guaranteed to run after the record has been fully committed to the database, as are Queueable classes. You may use either design to defer logic until after the final database commit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this method can be run synchronously, you can use a trigger.

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (after insert, after update) {
   code_block
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm

Comment: but after insert or whatever trigger contexts are run before DML commit happens right ? but what i need is something that can execute my code POST COMMIT